# Linux C++ gdb command for user input

Tags: c++, linux

I am coding in C++ in Linux. I have handled the ctrl C signal so that I could clean up all the resources upon exit. However, I have the problem when I run gdb. Ctrl C is also the stopping of the gdb command. Hence, how do I send the ctrl C to my programme so that I could test my written resource clean up code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At gdb's command prompt:

```
signal SIGINT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell GDB to pass the signal through to your program and not stop:

```
(gdb) handle SIGINT pass nostop
```